# Adding a pivot table to a new sheet with data on the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

My code creates a new sheet as per below code which is `ws2` where I have a table extracted from `ws1`. I want to place a pivot table on the same sheet `ws2` in cell "L4" as per bottom part of the code, but it would not work.

```
Sub ClickThisMacro()

Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim n As Long

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets.Add

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("Name")

fr = rng1.Row
lr = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
y = 2

For i = fr + 1 To lr
    ws2.Cells(y, 1) = ws1.Cells(i, 1)
    ws2.Cells(y, 2) = ws1.Cells(i, 2)
    ws2.Cells(y, 3) = ws1.Cells(i, 3)
    ws2.Cells(y, 4) = ws1.Cells(i, 4)
    ws2.Cells(y, 5) = ws1.Cells(i, 18)

    y = y + 1
Next i

ws2.Cells(1, 1) = "Cost centre name"
ws2.Cells(1, 2) = "Cost centre code"
ws2.Cells(1, 3) = "Phone number"
ws2.Cells(1, 4) = "User name"
ws2.Cells(1, 5) = "Amount"

LastRow = ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

' making columns C and F numbers
ws2.Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Select

For Each xCell In Selection
    xCell.Value = xCell.Value
Next xCell

With ws2.UsedRange.Columns(5)
    .Replace "£", "", xlPart
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Formula = .Value
End With

With ws2.UsedRange.Columns(8)
    .Replace "£", "", xlPart
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Formula = .Value
End With

'Pivot table
Dim mypivot As PivotTable
Dim mycache As PivotCache

Set mycache = ws2.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range("a1").CurrentRegion)

Set mypivot = ws2.PivotTables.Add(mycache.Range("l4"), "Mypivot1")

mypivot.PivotFields("Cost centre name").Orientation = xlRowField
mypivot.PivotFields("Cost centre code").Orientation = xlColumnField
mypivot.PivotFields("Amount").Orientation = xlDataField

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your code at the section where you set your `PivotCache` and `PivotTable` objects.

***Modified code*** (Pivot-Table section)

```
' set the Pivot-Cache
Set mycache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set mypivot = ws2.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=mycache, TableDestination:=ws2.Range("L4"), TableName:="Mypivot1")

With mypivot
    .PivotFields("Cost centre name").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Cost centre code").Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotFields("Amount").Orientation = xlDataField
End With
```

---

Some Other modifications/suggestions you should add to your code:

1. Using `Find` you should handle a scenario (even though unlikely) that you won't find the term you are looking for, in that case if `Rng1 = Nothing` then `fr = Rng1.Row` will result with a run-time error.

Dealing with `Find` code:

```
Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("Name")
If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then ' confirm Find was successfull
    fr = Rng1.Row
Else ' if Find fails
    MsgBox "Critical Error, couldn't find 'Name' in column A", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

2. You should avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, you can use fully qualified `Range` object instead:

Looping through a Range:

```
For Each xCell In ws2.Range("C2:C" & lr)
    xCell.Value = xCell.Value
Next xCell
```

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely perfect!